# Listbox remove wrong item

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have 3 ListBoxes in my page. I want to remove one selected item from ListBox. In ListBox1 it works good but when i select item from other ListBoxes and click remove - it remove always first item.

```
 protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem);
        }
        else if (ListBox2.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            ListBox2.Items.Remove(ListBox2.SelectedItem);
        }
        else if (ListBox3.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            ListBox3.Items.Remove(ListBox3.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's neither clearly what the desired behavior is, nor what the behavior you are currently seeing is; please clarify these points.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the rest of your statements aren't being reached by your `else if` statements.

Try this:

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (ListBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
            ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem);

        if (ListBox2.SelectedIndex != -1)
            ListBox2.Items.Remove(ListBox2.SelectedItem);

        if (ListBox3.SelectedIndex != -1)
            ListBox3.Items.Remove(ListBox3.SelectedItem);
}
```

Comment: The requirements seem to be that only one item should be removed, not one item from each.

Comment: @Servy, so that means the `if` statements would still be the problem but they need a `return` in them.

Comment: @neoistheone Or just using `else if` instead of three `if` statements ;)

Comment: @Servy, LOL, yeah I guess that would be the case. Man, I need another cup of coffee I guess; or a break one!

Comment: @Servy Nice observation. Haha

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Remove the ListBox Item you should always check all the ListBox's for selected Items , in your current code if first ListBox is not selected  then it won't even go for checking the rest of the ListBox's as you have written if-else block .

Hence Change as Below:

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ListBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem);
            }
            if (ListBox2.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                ListBox2.Items.Remove(ListBox2.SelectedItem);
            }
            if (ListBox3.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                ListBox3.Items.Remove(ListBox3.SelectedItem);
            }
        }
```

Comment: +1 as you're is also correct. But you have to do a better job of explaining yourself. The change is so subtle it's not easily seen.

Comment: @neoistheone I thought the change was immediately obvious.  But that's just me...

Comment: 1) It's simply a poor quality answer; it doesn't describe the change at all.  Being correct but unclear is quite problematic 2) it's not clear at all that this is the desired behavior.  The OP states that the click should remove *one* item, not one item from *each* listbox.

Comment: @Servy: but OP wants remove only the selected item from listbox in that case remaining listbox's contain index -1

Comment: @Sudhakar What?  That comment makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Servy: I Edited my Answer. Please check it now.

Comment: Again, it doesn't appear to match the OP's requirements.  He stated he wants the button click to remove *one* item, not one item from each listbox.

Comment: use if instead of else if it did not help

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not the best worded question.

Perhaps you only want to remove the currently selected item in **whatever ListBox was last used?**

If so, create a Form level variable to track what ListBox last changed its SelectedIndex:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private ListBox CurrentListBox = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
        ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
        ListBox3.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
    }

    void ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentListBox = (ListBox)sender;
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CurrentListBox != null && CurrentListBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            CurrentListBox.Items.Remove(CurrentListBox.SelectedItem);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thats good but then,would be better(since working with the current item) to refactor the code(of the button4 handler) in a new method and call it in the selectedindex handler deleting the item in place.

Comment: @terrybozzio But then the item would disappear as soon as you selected it...probably not what the user expects.  What if they click the wrong item?!

Comment: ohh,if  that happen inside the if statement you can place a messagebox for example warning the user about what item is going to be deleted if result is ok delete it else place the CurrentListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;...and the user can happily select another one :).

Comment: @terrybozzio I hope I never have to use one of your apps.

Comment: what,you wanted for this example to do a whole batch validation? common...ahhhh or is it just because i said something about your answer that you reply me in a not so mature way.By the way i said your answer is good and still do the best here for what i think the OP wants +1,and sorry if i offended your sensibility

Comment: LOL...don't take that the wrong way.  I just would hate an app that immediately popped up a MessageBox whenever I clicked an item in a ListBox.  Making a different selection would be incredibly painful as you'd have to move the mouse and dismiss the box.  The approach I gave needs improvement, perhaps with some way to visually indicate which ListBox is the "active" one.

Comment: It probably just makes more sense to unselect all options in all of the list boxes other than the current one whenever you select an item, rather than allowing selections across multiple checkboxes but ignoring some of them.

Comment: Agreed.  It's still unclear if the original intent was to delete all selected items, or just the one in the last used ListBox.